# how do you implement an EventDispatcher the rust way?

Tags: c++, rust

So I have been trying to create a rendering engine using rust, and I've been basing it on some C++ code that does the same thing. And I'm stuck on how you write an event dispatcher the rusty way.
here's the C++ code

```
class EventDispatcher {
    template<typename T>
    using EventFn = std::function<bool(T&)>;
public:
    EventDispatcher(Event& event) : m_Event(event) {}

    template<typename T>
    bool Dispatch(EventFn<T> func) {
        if (m_Event.GetEventType() == T::GetStaticType()) {
            m_Event.m_Handeled = func(*(T*)&m_Event);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
private:
    Event& m_Event;
};
```

and it will be used like this

```
void SomeOtherClass::OnEvent(Event& e) {
    EventDispatcher dispatcher(e);
    dispatcher.Dispatch<RandomEvent>(std::bind(&Application::EventHandler, this, std::placeholders::_1));
}
```

I've tried to implement a similar pattern in rust, this is what I've got so far

```
pub struct EventDispatcher<T: EventTrait> {
    event: Box<T>,
}

impl<T: EventTrait> EventDispatcher<T> {
    pub fn dispatch<V: EventTrait>(&mut self, func: impl Fn(&mut V) -> bool) -> bool {
        if self.event.type_id() == TypeId::of::<V>() {
            let res = func(unsafe { &mut *(self.event as *mut T as *mut V) });
            self.event.set_is_handeled(res);
            return res;
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is horribly wrong, I'm still trying to learn rust. Any help would be greatly appreciated! :D

Comment: At first glance it looks like a use case for an Event [`enum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html#defining-an-enum) where each kind of event is a variant of that enum. `self.event.type_id() == TypeId::of::<V>()` is almost certainly not how you want to go about this. Runtime reflection is extremely limited in Rust.

Comment: Oh, I should have clarified more, Event is any kind of struct that implements the EventTrait trait, so in this case, that line checks if they are of the same struct. At least that's how it goes in my mind

Comment: Yes, and that is not a pattern that is well suited for Rust. Will you need callers of this code to be able to supply their own `EventTrait` types?

Comment: the idea was that callers can receive events, say for example GLFW resize event, they generate an appropriate Event (this serves to abstract away the events, in case I move to Glutin once I learn it well enough) and then dispatch the event and its handler

Answer (score 0):

well I figured that my current approach wasn't the best, I tried to implement the observer pattern for this problem, and I feel that it's a better fit!

```
pub trait IObserver {
    fn update(&self, event: &impl EventTrait);
}

pub trait ISubject<'a, T: IObserver> {
    fn attach(&mut self, observer: &'a T);
    fn detach(&mut self, observer: &'a T);
    fn notify(&self, event: &impl EventTrait);
}
```